# Table appears empty without any value (Django)

Tags: html, django

My data are like this :

```
13.2610136284,20.8676059554,11.6376896892,0.51203356592,167,20154.4815106,
395,766,56,55047.3477967,-26818.1766435,3072.97868784,12.5402166873,-1443.
74556748,-4.0
```

I need to display it as a table in html
This is the function used in python to transform the data suitable for a table

```
import string
from datetime import datetime, date

def ratio_fil():

 ratioFil = open('sergRatiosOut20170426','r')
 rat = ratioFil.read().split(',')
 ratioFil.close()

 return rat
```

Rat is similar to this :

```
['13.2610136284', '20.8676059554', '11.6376896892', '0.51203356592', 
'167', '20154.4815106', '395', '766', '56', '55047.3477967', 
'-26818.1766435', '3072.97868784', '12.5402166873', '-1443.74556748', 
'-4.0\r\n']
```

I need to put it in a table, So i create a data_table tags :

```
<tr><td>X</td>              
 <td>{{data_table.0|floatformat:1}} %</td></tr>

<tr><td>y</td>      
        <td>{{data_table.1|floatformat:1}} %</td></tr>

<tr><td>y1 </td>        
 <td>{{data_table.2|floatformat:1}}  </td></tr>

<tr><td>y2</td>         
        <td>{{data_table.3|floatformat:1}}  </td></tr>
```

In Html :

```
       <div> {% with rat as data_table %}
              {% include 'tags/data_table.html' %}
             {% endwith %}
       </div>
```

The table appears empty, i think it should be a method to import rat ? Please i need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use builtin [for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) template tag to loop through and render the data in HTML table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column Name</th>
  </tr>
  {% for data in data_table %}
  <td>
     <td>{{ data }} </td>
  </td>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Remember to return the data from your view

```
def ratio_fil():

 ratioFil = open('sergRatiosOut20170426','r')
 rat = ratioFil.read().split(',')
 ratioFil.close()

 return render(request, 'template_name.html', {'data_table': rat})
```